# как узнать куда команда rm перенесла удаляемые файлы в Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

как узнать куда команда rm перенесла удаляемые файлы в Ubuntu?
Не могу нигде их найти, чтобы удалить безвозвратно и очистить память.

Comment: Да, похоже, что они автоматически удаляются безвозвратно?

Comment: Посмотрите type rm, если это не  alias, не ишите,  их больше нет.

Comment: Довольно часто задаваемый вопрос убунтологов. И самый частый ответ: посмотрите в Корзине.

Comment: что значит "безвозвратно"? Физически могут остаться на диске данные. Можно shred использовать. Для ssd могут специальные меры потребоваться.

Answer (score 7):

Команда *rm* удаляет файлы безвозвратно. Это означает, что она освобождает inode этого файла. После этого найти данные, относящиеся к этому файлу практически невозможно.

Если Вы хотите удалять в корзину, используйте команду *trash* (man 1 trash).  Если Вы желаете пользоваться только удалением в корзину и ничем другим, пропишите в Вашем *.bashrc* алиас:

```
alias rm='trash'
```

Если Вы параноик по безопасности, то поступите наоборот.

Начиная с версии файловой системы ext4 корзина поддерживается ядром. Но здесь я ничего конкретного сказать не могу - не пользовался.

Comment: не полное восстановление можно провести, если файлы еще открыты каким либо процессом - используя  **lsof** например